# Reduce the width of two side-by-side geom_violins while maintaining the sizes of the individual violins

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I am trying to generate two side by side geom_violin plots and shrink the left 
and right boundaries, as well as the middle separator between the main categories of the 
x-axes of both plots. Here is a minimal example to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)
require(gridExtra)
require(cowplot)

# two major categories (cut) and five 
# subcategories (color) are enough for the purpose of this question
pi <- filter(diamonds, (cut=="Premium" | cut=="Ideal") & color<"I")
pi$cut <- factor(pi$cut)
pi$color <- factor(pi$color)

th1 <- theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none")

g1 <- ggplot(data=pi, aes(x=cut, fill=color, y=price)) +
  geom_violin(width=0.5) + th1

g2 <- ggplot(data=pi, aes(x=cut, fill=color, y=depth)) +
  geom_violin(width=0.5) + th1


grid.newpage()
grid.arrange(plot_grid(g1,g2, ncol = 2, rel_widths = c(0.3,0.3)))
```

This code will create something like the following:
[image]

I have marked the spaces that I would like to trim or reduce.
Please note that I'm aware that increasing the width parameter in geom_violin() will indeed reduce this spacing;
however, I want to keep the widths of the violins at 0.5 and only decrease the total width of the plot (without affecting the sizes of the violins). Also, please note that `rel_widths` of the `plot_grid` function does not help, since I need both plots to be the same widths.

I searched for a similar question and found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000989/change-plot-dimensions-in-ggplot2); however, the answer uses a "print" statement and is for one plot only. Can anyone please generalize that answer for my case as well?

For reproducibility of my example, I'm also listing my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] cowplot_0.7.0   gridExtra_2.2.1 ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyr_0.6.1     dplyr_0.5.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.10     assertthat_0.1   R6_2.2.0         plyr_1.8.4       gtable_0.2.0    
 [6] DBI_0.6-1        magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.1     lazyeval_0.2.0   labeling_0.3    
[11] tools_3.3.2      munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 tibble_1.3.0
```

**EDIT**
I just found the answer myself. The boundary spacing can be removed by adding `+ scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0))` to the ggplots. Inner spacing is controlled by the width parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to keep your code mostly intact, just add `position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)` as a parameter to your `geom_violin`. Change the width number as you please.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, also I used faceting instead of the clunky other functions like `grid.arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

th1 <- theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none")

pi %>% 
  mutate(log_price = log10(price)) %>% 
  gather(Attribute, Value, log_price, depth) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = Value, fill = color)) +
  geom_violin(width = 0.7) +
  th1 +
  facet_wrap(~ Attribute, scales = "free_y")
```

Looks like it automatically sets width to about 0.85

Comment: very good; however, your answer has two issues (1) the middle separator between different cut categories is almost removed (I want it reduced, not removed) and (2) what if I need to have the left plot in logarithmic scale and the right in linear scale (and I do need this indeed), how can I use your answer to do this? That's why I used grid.arrange. Anyway, I upvoted your answer because I learned a lot from your answer. Thanks.

Comment: plus if you use `geom_violin(width=0.5)` instead of `geom_violin()` in your answer, the shape of your plot will resort to the plot in my question.

Comment: 1) You should be able to just pop a `geom_violin(width = 0.7) +` or such in there. Play around to find the one you like the most.
2) I'll update the answer for the log transmormation